# Fitting to the system of equations with no analytical solution

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, nonlinear

I'm trying to fit linear combination of 2 functions to my experimental data set (it represents voltage of 2 photodiodes - Voc1 and Voc2 - connected in series under illumination - S)

```
A=0.02585

Voc1 = Voc /. Solve[S == Jos*(Exp[-Voc/A/n] (*correction: + -> -*) - 1) + Voc/R1, Voc] (*analytical solution for Voc1(S) exists/ n in range 1-1.3*)

S = Jo1*(Exp[Voc2/A] - 1) + Jo2*(Exp[Voc2/2/A] - 1) + Voc2/R2 (*there is no analytical solution for Voc2(S)*)
```

Sumaric formula:

```
V = Voc2 - Voc1 
(*Data have a format {S, V}*)
FindFit[Data1, {V, n>=1, n<1.3}, {{Jos, 0.001}, {Jo1, 0.001}, {Jo2, 0.001}, {R1, 1}, {R2, 1}, {n,1}}, S]
```

Is there a method to force Mathematica to search fitting parameters Jo1, Jo2 and R2 through the relation S(Voc2)? 
I have no experience in using Mathematica so I would be much greatful for any help.

Unfortunately, fitting of inverse function S(V) does not apply for my data sets. Here is a sample of it:

```
    Data1={{8.17926024190235, 0.0049607354},{9.11306735079205, 0.0060270454}, {9.1096811048767, 0.0068196254}, {9.06089104262243, 0.0073612254}, {9.00914826766689, 0.0079031154}, {8.95623378132195, 0.0083917854}, {8.90293263021852, 0.0087984254}, {8.84699512848895, 0.0091917854}, {8.78935864524477, 0.0095545854}, {8.73051529926951, 0.0098653254}, {8.66971519527397, 0.0101341754}, {8.60693489903036, 0.0103706954}, {8.54230329879151, 0.0105664954}, {8.47485959121811, 0.0107404254}, {8.40413509175443, 0.0108061454}, {8.33084454434797, 0.0108637654}, {8.25396856008997, 0.0109089754}, {8.17310875710804, 0.0108933554}, {8.0870817068989, 0.0108352454}, {7.99578195543749, 0.0107799754}, {7.89778001482876, 0.0107143454}, {7.79149407469702, 0.0105488154}, {7.67407687636607, 0.0103703054}, {7.54384115543517, 0.0101757754}, {7.39703743545827, 0.0099686454}, {7.22675261923796, 0.0097743054}, {7.02357786431742, 0.0095367154}, {6.77334717999891, 0.0092961854}, {6.45889499442783, 0.0090206954}, {6.06518825047829, 0.0087113154}, {5.61240381827561, 0.0084199154}, {5.14708207420644, 0.0081176654}, {4.70470243914156, 0.0077849554}, {4.29643132262188, 0.0074848554}, {3.92319437664502, 0.0072034054}, {3.58317544855741, 0.0069027254}, {3.27268364748247, 0.0065216754}, {2.98914120836355, 0.0061539954}, {2.73028672821911, 0.0057656154}, {2.49241759905868, 0.0054350454}, {2.27620169637421, 0.0051090754}, {2.08003377556223, 0.0047700154}, {1.90123061754104, 0.0044163954}, {1.73719102302619, 0.0040777254}, {1.58757519571475, 0.0037371954}, {1.4501217326252, 0.0034328054}, {1.32410417269611, 0.0031199154}, {1.20862029815765, 0.0027365154}, {1.10151533176473, 0.0025803654}, {1.00379108675529, 0.0022939354}, {0.914453951871111, 0.0019085854}, {0.832662638334616, 0.0015910074}, {0.756827133790399, 0.0013745034}, {0.686850186193142, 0.0011051674}, {0.622520887492753, 0.000778995400000001}, {0.563666996114991, 0.000530460400000001}, {0.510116270485618, 0.000317374400000001}, {0.461221925917687, 7.94834000000012*10^-5}, {0.416653539799391, -0.000145414599999999}, {0.375254632989399, -0.000345804599999999}, {0.338380875565239, -0.000547764599999999}, {0.305174574789875, -0.000737704599999999}, {0.27520688429479, -0.000907034599999999}, {0.248208310460424, -0.0011045946}, {0.224041763054218, -0.0012166146}, {0.202604131473906, -0.0013332146}, {0.183238085630038, -0.0014990346}, {0.165885039953145, -0.0016193446}, {0.150684428098565, -0.0017063546}, {0.137342150507561, -0.0018159246}, {0.125315704806843, -0.0019337946}, {0.114720387397129, -0.0020096746}, {0.105217339344606, -0.0020616246}, {0.0972590755878564, -0.0021219846}, {0.0895411298370715, -0.0021967846}, {0.0828873323701323, -0.0022448346}, {0.0772919418012306, -0.0023145546}, {0.0722972876616702, -0.0023672946}, {0.0674342167111384, -0.0024032346}, {0.0630688887588203, -0.0024410246}, {0.0591613484463375, -0.0024695346}, {0.0559288310652834, -0.0025231546}, {0.0525933202531018, -0.0025415146}, {0.0502933679668646, -0.0025812546}, {0.0475128968398378, -0.0026536246}, {0.0450412888350547, -0.0027130946}, {0.0434278422518622, -0.0027144646}, {0.0404413842625804, -0.0026979546}, {0.039045407313259, -0.0027078246}, {0.0378725242124778, -0.0027299846}, {0.0353323710914153, -0.0027638746}, {0.0337875867956411, -0.0027842846}, {0.033192591752108, -0.0027982546}, {0.0322256955135818, -0.0028089946}, {0.0306523214599065, -0.0028189546}, {0.0288157810281738, -0.0028417046}, {0.0278889573191649, -0.0028650446}, {0.0275513872678811, -0.0028357546}, {0.0271165651712778, -0.0029846746}, {0.0260924894169494, -0.0030191446}, {0.0248109886703715, -0.0029347746}, {0.0235980330400731, -0.0029162146}, {0.0227226474610585, -0.0029559646}, {0.0221677249470426, -0.0029830146}, {0.0219160413406012, -0.0029375046}, {0.0216299094193117, -0.0029340946}, {0.0211035766631969, -0.0029735446}, {0.0206344234228844, -0.0029864346}, {0.0195587923674228, -0.0029925846}, {0.0187978829911517, -0.0030057746}, {0.01791113181166, -0.0029968846}, {0.0172016605653833, -0.0029860446}, {0.0167211417245937, -0.0029816446}, {0.0164921893191065, -0.0029580146}, {0.0162462470984732, -0.0029940546}, {0.0161603606536308, -0.0030289146}, {0.0159259012046135, -0.0029600646}, {0.0157427627144515, -0.0029598746}, {0.0153766029052666, -0.0029816446}, {0.0150104430960816, -0.0029687546}, {0.0144555205820657, -0.0029468846}, {0.0142266853477175, -0.0029402446}, {0.0133512997687028, -0.0029616246}, {0.012824967012588, -0.0029624146}, {0.0001, 0}}
```

Other sample of data

```
   Data2={{7.66998, 0.0746971}, {8.71071, 0.0744526}, {8.72344, 0.0753476}, {8.66343, 0.0760575}, {8.59626, 0.0767095}, {8.52452, 0.0773267}, {8.44956, 0.077879}, {8.37184, 0.0783796}, {8.29023, 0.0788011}, {8.20451, 0.079142}, {8.1135, 0.0794288}, {8.01715, 0.0796146}, {7.91307, 0.0797254}, {7.8004, 0.0797356}, {7.67546, 0.0796569}, {7.53709, 0.0794985}, {7.38014, 0.0792506}, {7.19697, 0.0788934}, {6.97599, 0.0784274}, {6.70041, 0.0778609}, {6.34991, 0.0772021}, {5.9158, 0.0764115}, {5.43354, 0.0755682}, {4.95797, 0.0745928}, {4.51491, 0.0735294}, {4.11132, 0.0723891}, {3.74501, 0.0711492}, {3.41368, 0.0698042}, {3.11236, 0.0683672}, {2.8393, 0.0668464}, {2.59098, 0.0652619}, {2.36483, 0.063601}, {2.15964, 0.0618814}, {1.973, 0.0600974}, {1.80241, 0.058253}, {1.64752, 0.056351}, {1.50627, 0.0543909}, {1.37775, 0.0524134}, {1.26045, 0.0504159}, {1.15298, 0.0483989}, {1.05403, 0.0463526}, {0.964072, 0.0442964}, {0.882035, 0.0422363}, {0.806784, 0.0401821}, {0.737677, 0.0381474}, {0.674572, 0.0361018}, {0.616495, 0.0340911}, {0.563087, 0.0320886}, {0.514206, 0.0301336}, {0.469659, 0.0282288}, {0.428232, 0.0263684}, {0.389654, 0.0245556}, {0.354342, 0.0227987}, {0.322342, 0.0210955}, {0.292936,0.0194458}, {0.266132, 0.0178668}, {0.241347, 0.0163532}, {0.218908, 0.0149263}, {0.198124, 0.0135607}, {0.179512,0.0122718}, {0.162514, 0.0110569}, {0.147147, 0.00991298}, {0.132918, 0.0088625}, {0.120297, 0.00788408}, {0.108803, 0.00697392}, {0.0984935, 0.00612861}, {0.0889791, 0.00535918}, {0.0807749, 0.00466298}, {0.0732857, 0.00403193}, {0.0666891, 0.00346289}, {0.0604873, 0.00293222}, {0.0553439, 0.00246484}, {0.0509042, 0.00204863}, {0.0464759, 0.00167333}, {0.0431976, 0.001358}, {0.0397535, 0.00104218}, {0.036767, 0.000766985}, {0.0342095, 0.000534075}, {0.032436, 0.000330364}, {0.0297928, 0.000160051}, {0.0283739, -0.000018073}, {0.0275158, -0.000172373}, {0.0256506, -0.000303523}, {0.0236883, -0.000438773}, {0.0228186, -0.000542683}, {0.0222522, -0.000659383}, {0.0213253, -0.000726663}, {0.0201468, -0.000851663}, {0.0186535, -0.000914073}, {0.0176065, -0.00102354}, {0.0170974, -0.00109473}, {0.0168513, -0.00115342}, {0.0164909, -0.00121641}, {0.0158558, -0.00130352}, {0.0149747, -0.00135586}, {0.0140136, -0.00140098}, {0.0130982, -0.00145264}, {0.0125661, -0.00150489}, {0.011891, -0.0015501}, {0.0114791, -0.00159756}, {0.0113417, -0.00164112}, {0.0111873, -0.00168077}, {0.0111014, -0.00172334}, {0.0109699, -0.00174454}, {0.010844, -0.0017795}, {0.0105637, -0.00179297}, {0.0103348, -0.0018253}, {0.010003, -0.00185059}, {0.00971119, -0.00188653}, {0.00918483, -0.00190098}, {0.00895027, -0.00191885}, {0.00837813, -0.00192256}, {0.0080978, -0.00195332}, {0.00774308, -0.00197413}, {0.00743985, -0.0019918}, {0.00714235, -0.00200928}, {0.00686201, -0.0020253}, {0.00658738, -0.00204131}, {0.00636426, -0.00206768}, {0.00615257, -0.00207178}, {0.00595233, -0.00208672},{0.0058894, -0.00210313}, {0.00583791, -0.00211602}, {0.00576353, -0.00213135}, {0.0001, 0}}
```

Comment: try to define a function `voc2[s_?NumericQ]:= FindRoot[s==Jo1..etc..]` and then you will  need to use `NonLinearModelFit`

Comment: I wonder, why are you trying to measure the voltage of series-connected photodiodes? A photodiode is a current source, so if I were you, I would connect them in parallel and measure the total photocurrent. But maybe you have some special reason to be doing this.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. This is a kind of unwanted element in the circuit - under high carriers injection, another (Schottky) junction shows up between semiconductor (part of pn photodiode) and rear metal contact.

Comment: @george2079 Thank you for the advice, I have tried to use following definition for voc2    voc2[S_?NumericQ, Jo1_?NumericQ, Jo2_?NumericQ, R2_?NumericQ] := y /. FindRoot[ S == Voc2/R2 + Jo1 ( Exp[Voc2/A] - 1) + Jo2 (Exp[Voc2/A/2] - 1), {Voc2, 0.005}]  // for all tested combinations of starting values for fit and data sets I got message:  NonlinearModelFit::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal (...) or NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value (...) is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {125} at {Jos,Jo1,Jo2,R1,R2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

To start you have one data point that needs to be fixed.

```
7.94834000000012*E-05 -> 7.94834000000012*10^-5.
```

Probably copied from a different format for numbers.

### Examine the data

I am going to use the form from your original question. Using the minus sign in the exponent `Jos*(Exp[-Voc/A/n]` is not helpful.

My understanding is that you have a measurement of illumination, `S`,  and the difference between two photodiode voltages, `V = Voc2 - Voc1`.

You have a model which relates `S` to `Voc1` which is invertible.

```
S = Jos*(Exp[Voc1/A] - 1) + Voc1/R1
```

We can invert this so that `Voc1` is a function of `S`

```
Voc1[S_, Jos_, R1_] := R1 (Jos + S) -
  517/20000 ProductLog[20000/517 Jos R1 Exp[20000/517 (Jos + S) R1]]
```

The relationship between `S` and `Voc2` can not be inverted.

A function is defined to relate the two.

```
S[Voc2_, Jo1_, Jo2_, R2_] := 
 Jo1*(Exp[Voc2/A] - 1) + Jo2*(Exp[Voc2/2/A] - 1) + Voc2/R2
```

We can use this function to derive a pseudo-function that has `Voc2` as the input and outputs the illumination, `S`.

```
Voc2[Sdata_, Jo1_, Jo2_, R2_] := Module[
  {
   voc2
   },
  voc2 /. FindRoot[Sdata - S[voc2, Jo1, Jo2, R2], {voc2, 0}]
  ]
```

We can validate it via:

```
S[0.1, 0.001, 0.001, 1]
(* 0.152788 *)
```

and then

```
Voc2[0.152788, 0.001, 0.001, 1]
(* 0.1 *)
```

I analyzed the individual relationships to get an idea of the order of magnitude and shape of the data.

Eventually I was able to come up with numbers for the parameters that look somewhat like your data (see *Grid Search* below).

Sorry for the long piece of code below. It essentially plots the individual components of the contribution to `S` from `Voc1` in the upper left plot, the contributions to `S` from `Voc2` in the lower left plot, `S` from `Voc1`, `Voc2` and the difference (plus the data) in the upper right plot and finally only `S` vs `Voc2 - Voc1` and the data in the lower right plot.

Here is the code (that you can shrink in a notebook) followed by an image of the `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Column[{
     Column[{
       Style["Jos*(Exp[voc1/A]-1)", Red],
       Style["voc1/R1", Blue],
       Style["S[Voc1]", Black]
       }],
     Show[
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        Jos*(Exp[voc1/A] - 1) + voc1/R1, voc1
        },
       {voc1, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Black,
       AxesLabel -> {"S", "Voc1"}],
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        Jos*(Exp[voc1/A] - 1), voc1
        },
       {voc1, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Red],
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        voc1/R1, voc1
        },
       {voc1, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Blue],
      PlotRange -> All,
      AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
      ImageSize -> 380
      ],

     Column[{
       Style["Jo1*(Exp[voc2/A]-1)", Red],
       Style["Jo2*(Exp[voc2/2/A]-1)", RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0]],
       Style["voc2/R2", Blue],
       Style["S[Voc2]", Black]
       }],
     Show[
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        Jo1*(Exp[voc2/A] - 1) + Jo2*(Exp[voc2/2/A] - 1) + voc2/R2, voc2
        },
       {voc2, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Black,
       AxesLabel -> {"S", "Voc2"}],
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        Jo1*(Exp[voc2/A] - 1), voc2
        },
       {voc2, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Red],
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        Jo2*(Exp[voc2/2/A] - 1), voc2
        },
       {voc2, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0]],
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        voc2/R2, voc2
        },
       {voc2, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Blue],
      PlotRange -> All,
      AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
      ImageSize -> 380
      ]
     },
    Alignment -> Center],

   Column[{
     Column[{
       Style["Voc1[S]", Blue],
       Style["Voc2[S]", Black],
       Style["Voc2[S]-Voc1[S]", Red]
       }],
     Show[
      Plot[Voc1[S, Jos, R1], {S, 0, 9.1},
       PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> {"S", "V"}
       ],
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        S[voc2, Jo1, Jo2, R2], voc2
        },
       {voc2, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Black],
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        S[voc2, Jo1, Jo2, R2], 
        voc2 - Voc1[S[voc2, Jo1, Jo2, R2], Jos, R1]
        },
       {voc2, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Red],
      ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Red],
      PlotRange -> All,
      AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
      ImageSize -> 380
      ],

     Column[{
       "",
       "",
       Style["Voc2[S]-Voc1[S]", Red],
       Style["data (dots)", Red]
       }],
     Show[
      ParametricPlot[
       {
        S[voc2, Jo1, Jo2, R2], 
        voc2 - Voc1[S[voc2, Jo1, Jo2, R2], Jos, R1]
        },
       {voc2, 0, voc2Max},
       PlotStyle -> Red],
      ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Red],
      PlotRange -> All,
      AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
      ImageSize -> 380
      ]
     },
    Alignment -> Center]
   }],

 Grid[{
  {Control[{{Jos, 0.0032}, 0.001, 0.05, Appearance -> "Open"}],
   Control[{{R1, 1.4}, 0.0001, 5., Appearance -> "Open"}],
   Control[{{voc2Max, 0.215}, 0.01, 10., Appearance -> "Open"}]},
  {Control[{{Jo1, 0.002}, 0.0001, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open"}],
   Control[{{Jo2, 0.015}, 0.0001, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open"}],
   Control[{{R2, 2}, 0.0001, 5., Appearance -> "Open"}]
   }
  }]
 ]
```

Now the image of the `Manipulate`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I needed to use my full screen in order to see this as two rows and two columns. The image in stack exchange appears as a single column.

### Optimization

I created a function which computes the reconstructed voltage, `V`, from the input illumination, `S`.

```
modelFunction[Sdata_, Jos_, R1_, Jo1_, Jo2_, R2_] := Module[
  {
   voc1,
   voc2
   },

  voc1 = Voc1[Sdata, Jos, R1];
  voc2 = Voc2[Sdata, Jo1, Jo2, R2];

  voc2 - voc1
  ]
```

Unfortunately when I attempted to use `NonlinearModelFit` it would not run and gave error messages.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data1,
  {
   modelFunction[Sdata, Jos, R1, Jo1, Jo2, R2],
   0.01 > Jos > 0.0001, 3 > R1 > 0.1,
   01 > Jo1 > 0.0001, 0.5 > Jo2 > 0.001, 3 > R2 > 2
   },
  {
   {Jos, 0.0019}, {R1, 1},
   {Jo1, 0.001}, {Jo2, 0.024}, {R2, 2}
   },
  Sdata]
```

Here are the two error messages that repeated:

FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0. +Sdata} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {voc2$21459204} = {0.}. >>

ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[Sdata-S[voc2$21459204,Jo1,Jo2,R2],{voc2$21459204,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

### NMinimize

I was able to use `NMinimize` but it didn't really give meaningful results.

### Grid Search

Finally I constructed a function to sweep each variable over a region that I ***hoped*** covered the minimum.

```
searchData = Table[
   {
    objectiveFunction[data1[[20 ;; 124]], Jos, R1, Jo1, Jo2, R2],
    Jos, R1, Jo1, Jo2, R2
    },
   {Jos, 0.0014, 0.0033, 0.0002},
   {R1, 0.5, 1.4, 0.1},
   {Jo1, 0.0011, 0.002, 0.0001},
   {Jo2, 0.015, 0.034, 0.002},
   {R2, 1, 2.9, 0.2}
   ];
```

The objective function computes the cumulative error squared between the measured and reconstructed voltage:

```
objectiveFunction[data_, Jos_, R1_, Jo1_, Jo2_, R2_] := Module[
  {
   Sdata,
   V,
   voc1,
   voc2,
   Vrecon,
   residual
   },

  Sdata = data[[All, 1]];
  V = data[[All, 2]];
  Vrecon = Map[modelFunction[#, Jos, R1, Jo1, Jo2, R2] &, Sdata];

  (*Compute the residual*)
  residual = Vrecon - V;

  (*The objective function is the sum of the residuals squared*)
  Total@Map[#^2 &, residual]
  ]
```

On my machine it took an hour and a half to compute the 100,000 points.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The quality of the fit can be examined by looking at the `Manipulate`. Indeed the starting value for the parameters were adjusted to be the output from the grid search.

Comment: Dear Jack. Thank you so much for all this work! Your understanding of the problem is absolutely correct. I have tried to do some adjust of fitting parameters and you exactly pointed out mistake in the model - since 1st diode is polarised in opposite direction (V=Voc2-Voc1), the "-" should be also included in exp component (also there can be added little more freedom to Voc1 by introducing ideality factor n)- I corrected the code and added other sample of data (perhaps in 1st case something went wrong during measurments). Thank you again and I much appreciate your answer!

Comment: For sure: V=0 at S=0 is the solution, but  when correction is applied this is only 1 from 3 allowed cross points with S axis at V=0 (the "manual" example can be Jos=0.33, R1=0.07, Jo1=0.002 and Jo2=0.064). However still missing can be a factor which describes the difference in light intensity between reference solar cell and tested photodiode (S->a*S). Thanks again Jack!

Comment: BTW. Big miss that I cannot vote due to low reputation. I found your answer very useful, with your code simulations go much faster!